# Testing class with ArrayList private member

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I have a Java class with following implementation:

```
    class Some {
      private ArrayList<SomeObject> list = new...

      public void addToList(Long t) {
          SomeObject so = new SomeObject(new Date, t)
          list.add(so)
      } 

      private float fun1(ArrayList<SomeObject> x) {
      //some operations on list "list", 
      //res - result of float calculations based on list "x"
      return res
      }

      public float publicFun() {
         //some other operations on private list "list"
         return fun1(list);
      }
```

The question is how to test function `publicFun()` using Mockito, PowerMock or other testing tool ? To run this public function I have to mock private List but how can I do it ?

Comment: You can mock the `ArrayList` just like any other type. What did you try?

Comment: Why would you mock the list? You add elements to the list using addToList(), call your publicFun() method, and check that it returns the expected float result.

Comment: make `fun1` non-private and test it instead

Comment: I cant use method `addToList` because it creates objects with time stamp from now - see constructor for `SomeObjec`. Lets suppose I have a array of SomeObjects `someObjectsAraayWithElementsToTest` which can be used.

Answer (score 1):

In this example there are several problems caused by unwelcome dependencies:

1 `new Date()`
To solve it I suggest to introduce new interface

```
interface CurrentTimeProvider {
    Date getCurrentDate();
}
```

Implementation is obvious (I skip it for briefness)

2 `Is new ArrayList()`

- You can replace it with you own interface (containing only method you
  need)
- You can mock ArrayList itself
- You can use real impl of ArrayList and test it altogether

In result we get something like this:

```
class Some {
  private CurrentTimeProvider timeProvider;
  private ArrayList<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

  public void setTimeProvider(CurrentTimeProvider timeProvider) {
      this.timeProvider = timeProvider;
  }

  public void addToList(Long t) {
      SomeObject so = new SomeObject(timeProvider.getCurrentDate(), t)
      list.add(so)
  } 

  public float publicFun() {
     //some other operations on private list "list"
     return fun1(list);
  }
```

And test look look this:

```
CurrentTimeProvider timeProvider = mock(CurrentTimeProvider.class);
Some some = new Some();
some.setTimeProvider(timeProvider);

when(timeProvider.getCurrentDate).thenReturn(mock(Date.class));

//Invoke you method
some.publicFun();

//Put assert and verify here
```

Comment: You forgot to use your CurrentTimeProvider instead of using `new Date()`. Worth noting: Java 8 provides a Clock class with ready-to-use fake implementations to mock the current time.